# 500 Error from Microsoft Graph on create child in approot

Tags: java, android, microsoft-graph-api

Got the following error while trying to create a folder in my app folder:

```
com.microsoft.graph.http.GraphFatalServiceException: [This is an unexpected error from Graph, please report this at https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-android/issues]
        POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/special/approot/children
        SdkVersion : graph-android-v1.2.0
        Authorization : bearer <REDACTED>
{"folder":{},"name":"gg"}

        500 : Internal Server Error
        Duration : 234.839
        Cache-Control : private
X-Android-Sent-Millis : 1489454003081
        Content-Type : application/json
        x-ms-ags-diagnostic : {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"West US","Slice":"SliceA","ScaleUnit":"000","Host":"AGSFE_IN_2","ADSiteName":"WST"}}
        request-id : f25e8a83-5b40-493f-811c-7c9731790c9f
        Date : Tue, 14 Mar 2017 01:13:37 GMT
        Transfer-Encoding : chunked
        X-Android-Response-Source : NETWORK 500
        client-request-id : f25e8a83-5b40-493f-811c-7c9731790c9f
        X-Android-Received-Millis : 1489454003395
        {
        "error": {
        "code": "generalException",
        "message": "An unspecified error has occurred.",
        "innerError": {
        "request-id": "f25e8a83-5b40-493f-811c-7c9731790c9f",
        "date": "2017-03-14T01:13:37"
        }
        }
        }
```

Per the app folder and the create folder documentation, the request should work given I have "Files.ReadWrite.AppFolder" permission scope.

I created the folder manually and tried to access its metadata and it failed similarly:

```
com.microsoft.graph.http.GraphFatalServiceException: [This is an unexpected error from Graph, please report this at https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-android/issues]
        GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/special/approot:/gg:
        SdkVersion : graph-android-v1.2.0
        Authorization : bearer <REDACTED>

500 : Internal Server Error
        Duration : 199.4711
        Cache-Control : private
X-Android-Sent-Millis : 1489455064558
        Content-Type : application/json
        x-ms-ags-diagnostic : {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"West US","Slice":"SliceA","ScaleUnit":"003","Host":"AGSFE_IN_3","ADSiteName":"WST"}}
        request-id : 660fad6b-491a-4876-98c5-9160c9f8715c
        Date : Tue, 14 Mar 2017 01:31:19 GMT
        Transfer-Encoding : chunked
        X-Android-Response-Source : NETWORK 500
        client-request-id : 660fad6b-491a-4876-98c5-9160c9f8715c
        X-Android-Received-Millis : 1489455064872
        {
        "error": {
        "code": "generalException",
        "message": "An unspecified error has occurred.",
        "innerError": {
        "request-id": "660fad6b-491a-4876-98c5-9160c9f8715c",
        "date": "2017-03-14T01:31:20"
        }
        }
        }
```

There's a file in the app directory that I can access via its item id and get its contents without issues.

Any ideas what might be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Files.ReadWrite.AppFolder` scope is not currently supported, but cannot be removed for a list of reasons which are unfortunate. You will need to use a different scope, such as Files.ReadWrite, to gain access and create this folder.

Note that even after changing permissions requested by your app, you will need to reconsent to the app to get the new permissions. You can force that to happen to adding &prompt=consent to the end of the OAuth2 Authorization URL or you can remove consent to your app first from